# How can I get the trajectory of a SKSpriteNode's physicsBody?

Tags: swift, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

How can I get the trajectory (of which I will derive a point) of a moving SKSpriteNode ? Would I use its physicsBody.velocity value ? Or is there another variable I can use ? Basically, I'm trying to get a few points that the moving node will pass through.

Thanks!

Comment: I made an answer but realize I could improve it greatly if I had more information. In what ways are you using the SpriteKit physics? Does your object have a mass, is gravity affecting it, are you applying continuous force to it or just using impulses. I assume at the point you want to calculate the trajectory, you will not apply any more impulses or new forces on the object, correct?

Comment: Yes Will, that is correct. Zero gravity in the physicsWorld, nothing acting on it other than it's initial impulse.

Comment: In that case, my answer should be sufficient

Comment: I believe so. I have used that method before, but for some reason it's acting up. I'll try later and report back. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using physics to move it you should be able to use the velocity value of the physics body plus the position of the node it is attached to. If you want to get points on the same line as the velocity vector, you take the x position and the y position, and you add `t * velocity.dx` to the x position, and `t * velocity.dy` to the y position where t is just an arbitrary time when the node would reach that point.

Probably worth noting that this is the point velocity of the node. If it is set up to move in a path other than a straight line, such as a parabolic arc, this will take the straight line velocity at the given point, and return points on that line, as opposed to lines on the parabolic arc that it will travel. If you want points on a complex path that it will travel due to many different or changing forces, you will need to model those forces into an equation and plug your t into that.